# Django form field dynamic queryset field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

```
class EventForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
    product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all())
    isrecurring = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    week =  forms.IntegerField(required=False, initial=1)
    days =  forms.ChoiceField(choices = week_days,required=False)
```

I have a form that has a products field which is a query set of all products.

I want the field to filter products by company.

How can i set the form field to have dynamically queryset in the view such that the products are filtered based on the company id?

```
product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.filter(company=xyz))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class EventForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(company=company_id)
    # Where company_id is coming from either **kwargs or from the view.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting a __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'company_id' error. the code in form is as follows: 
    def __init__(self,company_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = company_id
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(company__id=id).
       

 Code in view: form_class = CompanyForm(company_id=id)

Comment: You're overloading `EventForm` init, but using `CompanyForm` after?